# FFmpeg How to Overlay two videos with 0.5 Transparency

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have one command which has some issues. if one video have shorted length then second video. first video will pause and second will continue to play.
other issue is that this command is very slow

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i Vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:0] setsar=sar=1,format=rgba [1sared]; [0:0]format=rgba [0rgbd]; [0rgbd][1sared]blend=all_mode='addition':repeatlast=1:all_opacity=1,format=yuva422p10le" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -tune film -crf 19 -c:a aac -shortest result.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

> if one video have shorted length then second video. first video will pause and second will continue to play

Replace `repeatlast=1` with `shortest=1`.

```
ffmpeg -h filter=blend
[...]
framesync AVOptions:
  eof_action        <int>        ..FV..... Action to take when encountering EOF from secondary input  (from 0 to 2) (default repeat)
     repeat                       ..FV..... Repeat the previous frame.
     endall                       ..FV..... End both streams.
     pass                         ..FV..... Pass through the main input.
  shortest          <boolean>    ..FV..... force termination when the shortest input terminates (default false)
  repeatlast        <boolean>    ..FV..... extend last frame of secondary streams beyond EOF (default true)
```

> this command is very slow

Use a faster [x264 preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).